# API gateway calling my elastic beanstalk environment using HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to figure out how I can call my elastic beanstalk environment with HTTPS. Ultimately I want to be able to use API gateway to forward HTTPS requests to it*.

In the elastic beanstalk console I went and configured the load balancer to use my website's SSL cert (mywebsite.com), on port 443 and with an instance port of 80 (whatever that means - I was following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html).

Before wiring up API gateway, I first tried calling my elastic beanstalk endpoint. Changing `http://` to `https://`, using postman I got

> Error: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host:
> myService-prod.eba-p3t3saxf.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com. is
> not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.mywebsite.com

No dice. I then thought maybe if the request originated from my website's domain it might work. So I tried configuring API gateway,  but I just get back a 500 Internal server error. (note if I change the `endpoint URL` inside API gateway from `https` to `http` all is good).

So what do I need to do? I tried reading this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html, but got only as far as I described above. I feel like I do need a certificate, but when I tried using Amazon's certificate manager to generate a certificate for myService-prod.eba-p3t3saxf.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com, I can't validate it (fails both email and DNS certification). I think I don't fully understand what I need to do/see the big pictures. Can someone help me out, ideally with specific instructions.

*Actually, that is a question in itself. If my API gateway endpoint is HTTPS, is it safe for API gateway to then call my elastic beanstalk environment with just HTTP, as we're already inside AWS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using Amazon's certificate manager to generate a certificate for myService-prod.eba-p3t3saxf.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com

You can't generated SSL certificate for this domain. This is AWS owned and manged domain. To get proper valid SSL certificate you have to have **your own domain** which you control.

From your post its not clear if you actually have a domain `mywebsite.com` or not. If not, and you want to keep yourself within AWS, you can use [Route53 to buy a domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-register.html) which you want. But any domain provider will be fine. Once you have your own custom domain, you can setup [hosted zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-working-with.html) in R53 for it, and [point it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html) to your EB's load balancer.

Having the domain setup, you can use AWS ACM to issue a valid, public free SSL certificate for your domain and deploy it on the load balancer.

In your API gateway you would use your EB domain for HTTP integrations, not AWS EB default domain.

Comment: yes I have domain which i bought through route53. what do I need to do in the hosted zones panel? what do I create. a CNAME? Can you give me specific steps?

Comment: I think I may have already have done what you described. I had ACM issue a cert for *.mywebsite.com and then I attached this to the load balancer through the console (steps described in my originaly post)

Comment: @Prof I [linked](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html) the setps in the answer. You need Alias A record. So does your custom domain work in https?

Comment: OK, still a little confused. I already have an alias A record for api.mywebsite.com which points to a cloudfront URL (I configured this a few weeks back can't remember what for now, but was around API gateway)

What do you mean by  "does your custom domain work in https". I can go to https://mywebsite.com and browse my website fine.

Comment: @Prof So you want to have API gateway -> CloudFront, or API gateway -> EB? Because your question suggests that you want the latter. If so, you have to have HTTPs setup on EB, not cloudfront.

Comment: I want to have API Gateway -> EB. When I went to Route53 to add an A record, I already had one setup for api.mywebsite.com which points to a cloudfront URL. I remember doing this when I was setting up API gateway to call lambdas a couple of weeks ago. I got this cloudfront URI from inside "Custom Domain Names" in API gateway.

Comment: @Prof You need a record for EB then, e.g. `myeb.mywebsite.com` which points to `myService-prod.eba-p3t3saxf.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`. You also need certificate for this new subdomain deployed on the EB load balancer.

Comment: and the record would be a CNAME record, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227778/discussion-between-prof-and-marcin).